# Problema al mostrar menú después de añadir CSS

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona correctamente, el problema es que no me funcionan los enlaces del menú y no entiendo muy bien porque solo le agregué estilos a la etiqueta `nav`. No entiendo por qué razón me sucede eso, ya vi todo el código y no encuentro dónde tendré el error.

Mi propósito es crear un menu que siga siempre al usuario. Espero que me puedan ayudar. Éste es mi código:

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  background: #ff7334;
}

.nav-content {
  background: #0D0D0D;
}

.page-footer {
  height: 505px;
  background: #000000;
}

.contactoinfo {
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

.tarjetas {
  color: #fff;
}

.producto16 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.parallax-container {
  height: 500px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.8" data-semver="1.3.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-translate@*" data-semver="2.5.0" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/2.5.0/angular-translate.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.tap-target').tapTarget('open');
  $('.tap-target').tapTarget('close');
</script>

<body ng-controller="translateController">

  <nav class="default" role="navigation">
    <center>
      <div style="background:black;" ng-controller="translateController">
        <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Idiomas</a>
        <ul style="float:right;" id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
          <li><a ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" href="#!">English</a></li>
          <li><a ng-click="changeLanguage('sp')" href="#!">Español</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </center>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Lovi Acabados</a>

      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse show-on-large"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="side-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="producto1.html"><img src="adoquin.png" width="115" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto1.html"><img src="Marmol.png" width="90" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto4.html"><img src="Block.png" width="80" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto5.html"><img src="Cantera.png" width="105" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto6.html"><img src="Esculturas.png" width="125" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto7.html"><img src="Fuentes.png" width="100" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto8.html"><img src="Granito.png" width="105" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto9.html"><img src="Iluminacion.png" width="230" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto11.html"><img src="Ladrillos.png" width="115" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto13.html"><img src="Piedras.decorativas.png" width="230" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto15.html"><img src="Pisos.png" width="100" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto17.html"><img src="Baños.png" width="100" height="55"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto16.html"><img src="Teja.png" width="80" height="50"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>


      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li style="padding-bottom:2px">
          <a href="producto1.html"><img src="adoquin.png" width="115" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto4.html"><img src="Block.png" width="90" height="50"></a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="producto5.html"><img src="Cantera.png" width="105" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto6.html"><img src="Esculturas.png" width="125" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto7.html"><img src="Fuentes.png" width="100" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto8.html"><img src="Granito.png" width="105" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto9.html"><img src="Iluminacion.png" width="230" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto11.html"><img src="Ladrillos.png" width="115" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto13.html"><img src="Piedras.decorativas.png" width="230" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto15.html"><img src="Pisos.png" width="100" height="50"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto17.html"><img src="Baños.png" width="100" height="55"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="producto16.html"><img src="Teja.png" width="80" height="50"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Éste es el error que me sale:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como debería estar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: ignoren los botones de idiomas, ellos no son el problema. El problema es cuando le agrego el CSS al `nav` sucede eso.

Comment: Lo que estás indicando como enlace es lo que te sale: `<a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Lovi Acabados</a>` si quieres que sea `index.php` debes ponerlo en el `href`: **`<a href="index.php" class="brand-logo center">Lovi Acabados</a>`**

Comment: Quítale el `z-index` a los estilos del `nav` y prueba de nuevo. ¿Funciona así?

Comment: Es lo primero que hice y tampoco funciona.

Comment: *"Uncaught TypeError:* `$(...).tapTarget` *is not a function",*